# Android SurfaceTexture timestamp is always zero

Tags: android, opengl-es, surface

Step 1:

Created Surface Texture using OPENGL

```
int[] textures = new int[1];
// Generate the texture to where android view will be rendered
GLES30.glActiveTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES30.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0]);

GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES30.GL_NEAREST);
GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);
GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Step 2:

Creating Surfacetexture

```
mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mGlSurfaceTexture);
mSurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mViewWidth, mViewHeight);
```

Getting zero when using `surfaceTexture.getTimestamp()`

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture#getTimestamp()

> Retrieve the timestamp associated with the texture image set by the most recent call to updateTexImage().
>
> This timestamp is in nanoseconds, and is normally monotonically
> increasing. The timestamp should be unaffected by time-of-day
> adjustments. The specific meaning and zero point of the timestamp
> depends on the source providing images to the SurfaceTexture.

It sounds like the timestamp relates only to calls to `updateTexImage` which it seems like you haven't called (unless you missed out that detail in the question).

It also sounds like the timestamp has no specific base, and should only be measured relative to previous calls to `updateTexImage`, so a timestamp of 0 would be reasonable even after calling `updateTexImage` once on an instance.